# Traversing through PHP array

Tags: php

I am scraping a website. I am able to get most of the contents but just stuck in one last thing, that is; when i get traverse through the employer(company) name and its location. And I push them to an array named `$places`. When I print that array it looks like this :

```js
Array
(
    [0] => Confidential

)
Array
(
    [0] => Palm Bay, FL

)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Robert Half Technology
    [2] => 

)
Array
(
    [0] => Santa Monica, CA

)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Apex Systems
    [2] => 

)
```

on each `$a->nodeValue` it prints the value, but when i push it to the array `$places`, it pushed sub array to that array and have many indices. I dont know why. Can you test my code and see how it is :

```js
set_time_limit(500);

$link = "https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobs-web-developer-in-usa?keywords=software+developer&location=usa&page_number=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$title = array();
$when = array();
$timing = array();
$company = array();
$location = array();
$paths = array();
$salary = array();
$summary = array();

@$document = new DOMdocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
@$document - > loadHTML($data);
$elements = @$document - > getElementsByTagName("div");

foreach($elements as $element) {
  if ($element - > getAttribute("class") == "job-row") {
    foreach($element - > childNodes as $sublements) {
      if ($sublements - > hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach($sublements - > childNodes as $nodes) {
          if ($nodes - > hasChildNodes()) {
            foreach($nodes - > childNodes as $node) {
              if ($node - > hasChildNodes()) {
                switch ($node - > getAttribute("class")) {
                  case 'job-title show-for-medium-up':
                    {
                      array_push($title, $node - > nodeValue);
                      break;
                    }
                  case 'show-for-medium-up':
                    {
                      array_push($when, $node - > nodeValue);
                      break;
                    }
                  case 'job-text employment-info':
                    {
                      array_push($timing, $node - > nodeValue);
                      break;
                    }
                  case 'job-description show-for-medium-up':
                    {
                      array_push($summary, $node - > nodeValue);
                      break;
                    }
                  case 'job-text':
                    {
                      $places = array();
                      foreach($node - > childNodes as $a) {
                        array_push($places, $a - > nodeValue);
                      }
                      echo "<pre>";
                      print_r($places);
                      echo "<pre>";
                      break;
                    }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Don't insert in the question a code snippet that cannot be executed. Use the `{}` button in the toolbar to format it as code instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I was getting into the children.

```js
<?php
       

       #$link = "https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobs-web-developer-in-".$loc."?keywords=".$title."&location=".$loc."&page_number=".$start;
      set_time_limit(500);

      $link = "https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobs-web-developer-in-usa?keywords=software+developer&location=usa&page_number=1";
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
       $data = curl_exec($ch);

        #"https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=&start=";

       $title = array ();
       $when = array ();
       $timing = array ();
       $company = array ();
       $location = array ();
       $paths = array ();
       $salary = array ();
       $summary = array ();
       $places = array ();

       
       

       @$document = new DOMdocument();
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
       @$document->loadHTML($data);
       $elements = @$document->getElementsByTagName("div");

       foreach($elements as $element){
           if($element->getAttribute("class")=="job-row"){
             foreach($element->childNodes as $sublements){
              if($sublements->hasChildNodes()){
                 foreach ($sublements->childNodes as $nodes) {
                   if($nodes->hasChildNodes()){
                     foreach ($nodes->childNodes as $node) {
                       if($node->hasChildNodes()){
                        switch ($node->getAttribute("class")) {
                          case 'job-title show-for-medium-up':{
                            array_push($title, $node->nodeValue);
                            if($node->hasChildNodes()){
                              foreach($node->childNodes as $l){
                                if($l->hasChildNodes()){
                                  array_push($paths, $l->getAttribute("href"));
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            break;
                          }
                          case 'show-for-medium-up':{
                            array_push($when, $node->nodeValue);
                            break;
                          }
                          case 'job-text employment-info':{
                            array_push($timing, $node->nodeValue);
                            break;
                          }
                          case 'job-description show-for-medium-up':{
                            array_push($summary, $node->nodeValue);
                            break;
                          }
                          case 'job-text':{
                            array_push($places, $node->nodeValue);
                            break;
                          }
                        }
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
       }
       
       for($i=0;$i<sizeof($places);$i++){
        if($i%2==0){
          array_push($company, $places[$i]);
        }else{
          array_push($location, $places[$i]);
        }
       }

       print_r($title);
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($paths);
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($when);
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($timing);
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($summary);
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($location);
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
       print_r($company);

       curl_close($ch);


?>
```